# How to click the self contained <a> of an <li>?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the JS I've tried:

```
$('#footer').find('.browse li').click(function(e){
            $(this).find('a').click();
        });
```

Here's the HTML in question:

```
<div id="footer" class="span-24"><div class="footer-box"><div class="footer-holder">
    <div class="browse">
        <ul>
           <li><a href="xyz">123</a></li>
           <li><a href="xyz">123</a></li>
           <li><a href="xyz">123</a></li>
           <li><a href="xyz">123</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div></div></div>
```

How can I make the `<a>` click if the `<li>` is clicked?

**PS.** This is due to a css design (the LI has a bunch of padding and a background that can't be put on the A)

Comment: what doesn't work with your code ?

Comment: clicking the li doesn't activate the a (go to the link of the a).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your call to `.click()` just triggers anything bound to the `a`'s `click` event. I think what you want is something like this:

```
$('#footer').find('.browse li').click(function(){
   window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
}
```

Comment: That works. If only there was a way to handle a normal click on the link would be awesome (just in case that link had other js bound to it's click as well).

Comment: @user1049097 If that's a concern you can continue to manually trigger it like you were doing before~ =) `$(this).find('a').click().attr('href');`

Answer (score 4):

Are you just missing a click event for the `a`?  Example:

```
$('.browse li').click(function(e){
            $(this).find('a').click();
        });

$('a').click(function(){
   alert("a clicked");
    return false;
});
```

see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LRMqD/3/

On the other hand, if you are just trying to redirect to the href try this code:

```
$('.browse li').click(function(e){
            window.location.href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
        });
```

Comment: What I meant was how can I make it go to the href of the `a`? -- i.e. make it visit `xyz`.

Comment: That works. If only there was a way to handle a normal click on the link would be awesome (just in case that `a` also had js bound to it's click as well).

Comment: @user1049097, you could use the `$('a').click(function(){` code from my first example and combine it with the `window.location.href` from my second to hand the click event on `a`.  Not sure you would need to though.

Answer (score 1):

Please do not attach an event handler to every single element.

Use [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead:

```
$('#footer').find('.browse li').delegate('a', 'click', function(e){
    var elt = e.target;
    console.log('clicked a number '+elt.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

to make `<a>` click, you need to do a `trigger`.

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

```
$('#footer').find('.browse li').click(function(e){
    $(this).find('a').trigger('click');
});
```